# easiest way to write a title page to pdf without Sweave

Tags: r, pdf, sweave

I have R code (using ggplot2) that pumps out a bunch of charts to PDF and I'm happy with the layout.  I just want to slap on a decent-looking title page which is just some centered text.  Google seems to produce a lot of support for Sweave - except that the workflow is really bizarre to me (i.e. embed my R in sweave, run sweave from R).  Also, I don't want to onboard a bunch of new programs to get this to work.  Also, I have a ton of R code that produces the charts and I'm happy with the flow-of-control (i.e. run r script, r script writes plots to pdf).  Ideally, I just want to print a title page to the PDF, print my plots, close the device, and call it a day.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you want to do it totally within R, this could work, but it is a poor substitute for using actual typesetting software (as opposed to statistical analysis software) to make title pages:

```
#pdf(...)
plot(0:10, type = "n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlab = "", ylab = "")


text(5, 8, "This is the title")
text(5, 7, "This is my name")

text(5, 6, "This is the date")

#plot(...)/xyplot(...)/ggplot(...) your plots

#dev.off()
```

[image: Title Page in R]

Comment: Before you close the device, you can add your plots into one pdf.

Comment: @Greg - I agree that ideally I would use typesetting software.  What is the best practice for my scenario?  Is it literally to wrap my R code in a LATEX doc with sweve markup and then run sweve?  Is there a way to use typesetting with flow-of-control from R?

Comment: @Greg - also, how would I change the font face / size?

Comment: I once made the slides of an entire presentation like this in R, then I discovered Sweave and beamer:)

For just a small informative title page or some text I'd prefer to do it like this though because it makes your code reproducible by people who don't have a LaTeX distribution.

For font/size, look at `help('text')`

Comment: @Sacha - were you able to change font face / size?

Comment: R, using Greg's solution above.

Comment: @SFun28 you can use a combination `font` and `family` parameters to text to modify the text type, as well as `cex` for size. See `?text` and `?par` for more info.

Comment: this is a good resource for layout: http://rgraphics.limnology.wisc.edu/rmargins_sf.php

Comment: Is there some way to find which coordinates to use in the text command ? i.e. whether to use 5, 7 or 4, 8 or is it hit and trial ?